# In AIR/AS3 How to capture image of whats visible on the stage and save that image as anything like jpg/pdf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex-mobile

In AIR/AS3 Flex Mobile for Android project.

How can I capture an "image" of whats visible on the view

then just save that image as anything like jpg/pdf to the SD card?

Basically a screenshot on Android using AS3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private function getBitmapData( target:DisplayObject ) : BitmapData
{

   //target.width and target.height can also be replaced with a fixed number.
   var bd : BitmapData = new BitmapData( target.width, target.height );
   bd.draw( target );
   return bd;
}
```

Create the byte array using `JPEGEncoder` and save this to Your sd card. In some case if the width and height of the target is not working, You can use the `getbounds` method to get the bounds of the object and from the bounds take the `width` and `height`.

Comment: Can you give a full example of how to do this? I have been trying this code to no avail.